# I need my GLSL fragment shader to return the distance calculation

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm using some standard GLSL (version 120) vertex and fragment shaders to simulate LIDAR. In other words, instead of just returning a color at each x,y position (each pixel, via the fragment shader), it should return color and distance.

I suppose I don't actually need all of the color bits, since I really only want the intensity; so I could store the distance in `gl_FragColor.b`, for example, and use `.rg` for the intensity. But then I'm not entirely clear on how I get the value back out again.

Is there a simple way to return values from the fragment shader? I've tried `varying`, but it seems like the fragment shader can't write variables other than `gl_FragColor`.

I understand that some people use the GLSL pipeline for general-purpose (non-graphics) GPU processing, and that might be an option — except I still do want to render my objects normally.

Comment: What do you want to return the fragment shader output *to*?  Host memory?  A texture?

Comment: I suppose host memory. I'm not quite sure how to answer that question. I'd like to just be able to get the value out of the buffer, I suppose. The more I think about this, the more it seems like it just makes sense to store it in a color channel. Is there some way to not interfere with color storage, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL already returns this "distance calculation" via the depth buffer, although it's not linear. You can simply create a frame buffer object (FBO), attach colour and depth buffers, render to it, and you have the result sitting in the depth buffer (although you'll have to undo the depth transformation). This is the easiest option to program provided you are familiar with the depth calculations.

Another method, as you suggest, is storing the value in a colour buffer. You don't have to use the main colour buffer because then you'd lose your colour or have to render twice. Instead, attach a second render target (texture) to your FBO (`GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`) and use `gl_FragData[0]` for normal colour and `gl_FragData[1]` for your distance  (for newer GL versions you should be declaring `out` variables in the fragment shader). It depends on the precision you need, but you'll probably want to make the distance texture 32 bit float (`GL_R32F` and write to `gl_FragData[1].r`).
- This is a decent place to start: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object

Yes, GLSL can be used for compute purposes. Especially with ARB_image_load_store and nvidia's bindless graphics. You even have access to shared memory via compute shaders (though I've never got one faster than 5 times slower). As @Jherico says, fragment shaders generally output to a single place in a framebuffer attachment/render target, and recent features such as image units (ARB_image_load_store) allow you to write to arbitrary locations from a shader. It's probably overkill and slower but you could also write your distances to a buffer via image units .

Finally, if you want the data back on the host (CPU accessible) side, use `glGetTexImage` with your distance texture (or `glMapBuffer` if you decided to use image units).

Comment: I wish I could vote this answer up multiple times. Thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment shaders output to a rendering buffer.  If you want to use the GPU for computing and fetching data back into host memory you have a few options

- Create a framebuffer and attach a texture to it to hold your data.  Once the image has been rendered you can read back information from the texture into host memory.
- Use an [CUDA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131387685), [OpenCL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005BOMOX6) or an [OpenGL compute shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader) to write the memory into an arbitrary bound buffer, and read back the buffer contents

Comment: Can you add a link or something similar explaining how one would do this? I've heard these answers before but couldn't find a good reference.

Comment: I've added some links to relevant texts.